# Why does heob detect these as memory leaks in QCreator generated code?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I try to fix memory leaks in my app but most of them are from generated ui code from QCreator. Are they really memory leaks? For Example setting suffix like that is detected.

```
spinBox_trainingPeriod->setSuffix(QString::fromUtf8(" sec."));
```

Result:

```
16 bytes in 1 blocks are lost in loss record 8949 of 8951 (#248981)
  in calloc in 
  1: calloc in 
  2: public: static class QString QInputMethod::tr(char const *,char const *,int) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Gui.dll
  3: public: static class QString QInputMethod::tr(char const *,char const *,int) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Gui.dll
  4: public: static class QString QInputMethod::tr(char const *,char const *,int) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Gui.dll
  5: private: int QTextEngine::shapeTextWithHarfbuzzNG(struct QScriptItem const &,unsigned short const *,int,class QFontEngine *,class QVector<unsigned int> const &,bool,bool)const  in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Gui.dll
  6: private: void QTextEngine::shapeText(int)const  in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Gui.dll
  7: public: void QTextEngine::shape(int)const  in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Gui.dll
  8: private: void QTextLine::layout_helper(int) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Gui.dll
  9: public: void QTextLayout::endLayout(void) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Gui.dll
  10: private: int QWidgetLineControl::redoTextLayout(void)const  in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Widgets.dll
  11: private: void QWidgetLineControl::updateDisplayText(bool) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Widgets.dll
  12: private: bool QWidgetLineControl::finishChange(int,bool,bool) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Widgets.dll
  13: private: void QWidgetLineControl::internalSetText(class QString const &,int,bool) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Widgets.dll
  14: protected: virtual void QAbstractSpinBox::timerEvent(class QTimerEvent *) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Widgets.dll
  15: public: void QSpinBox::setSuffix(class QString const &) in C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017_64/bin/Qt5Widgets.dll
  16: Ui_widget_eyeblink::setupUi in C:/git/eyeblink/build-blink-desktop_qt_5_12_0_msvc2017_64bit2-release/ui_gui.h:1751
  17: EyeblinkGUI::EyeblinkGUI in C:/git/eyeblink/sources/eyeblinkgui.cpp:157
  18: EyeblinkApplication::EyeblinkApplication in C:/git/eyeblink/sources/application.cpp:219
  19: main in C:/git/eyeblink/sources/main.cpp:160
  20: WinMain in C:/git/eyeblink/build-blink-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release/release/eyeblink.exe
  21: __scrt_common_main_seh in f:/dd/vctools/crt/vcstartup/src/startup/exe_common.inl:288
```

Comment: Have you tried `Leak details: Detect Leak Types`? This should ignore all memory blocks that still have a reference from static/global variables (but also takes longer on program exit).

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bug in heob, because Deleaker is not detected these.